# How will search rankings get impacted if I move my mobile website to a single page application?

Tags: seo, google-search

I have two different versions of my site: a desktop version, and a mobile optimised version. That is, for the same URL, the server renders different HTML for different user agents. I had been using vary header for this scheme as recommended by Google.

However, now I want to move the mobile website to a single page application.

I want to know if Google stops seeing anything on my mobile web version but the desktop version continues to work as it is, then how would the search rank be impacted given that mobile web gets more traffic than the desktop version. How would the vary header come into play

Comment: When you say *single page application*, what are we talking about specifically? This may help to understand and answer your question.

Comment: I am planning to use backbone.js. so google wont be able to index anything...unless i implement phantom or sometho g else..

Comment: Sorry. I don't know anything about this. But I assume someone will. That is why I asked the question- to give you a better shot.

Answer (score 1):

A single page application can rank well in search engines for its brand terms.   If you have content embedded in this application, you'll want to implement [crawlable AJAX](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/).   Doing so allows you assign `#!` URLs to the deep content and allow them to rank in search engines.

Your existing mobile site can be redirected to the hash bang URLs of the single page application.

Answer (score 0):

So I assume by application you mean iOS & Android app?
Then to me it seems that you sacrifice your mobile SERP for the ranking of the app itself. Usually you can expect a noticable drop of the organic traffic, but it will be alright after some time(shouldn't be more then a month).